# get the total amount with HAVING and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, having

Let say I have a "orders" table and I have to print the list of customers that have spent more than 100$. To do so I use HAVING and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT clientID, SUM(amount) AS spent
FROM orders
GROUP BY clientID
HAVING spent >= 100;
```

Now I wonder if in the SAME query is possible to get the total amount spent by all this customers who spent more that 100$, and the total number of customers/rows.

- john > 125$
- doe > 100$
- **TOTAL > 225$ (2 client)**

Answer (score 2):

`WITH ROLLUP` is your friend.

```
SELECT clientID, SUM(amount) AS spent
FROM orders
GROUP BY clientID
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING spent >= 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI SQL-92 standard approach:

```
SELECT clientID, SUM(amount) AS spent
FROM orders
GROUP BY clientID
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 100;
```

The `WITH ROLLUP` approach will yield a row with null clientID and the `sum(amount)` across all clientIDs

MySQL will also support:

```
SELECT clientID, SUM(amount) AS spent
FROM orders
GROUP BY clientID
HAVING spent >= 100;
```

To answer the question actually asked:

```
SELECT clientID, SUM(spent) as spent
FROM (
  SELECT clientID, SUM(amount) AS spent
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY clientID
  HAVING spent >= 100
)
GROUP BY clientID
WITH ROLLUP;
```